# How to quickly and easily convert between R and pandas dataframes in Databricks?

Tags: r, pandas, databricks, temp-tables

I am an R user with minimal python experience. I have some colleagues who use python and I want to be able to easily convert between R and python/pandas dataframes in the same Databricks notebook. I have heard that I have to use spark temp tables to do this and that it is quite straightforward, but I cannot find any complete example code and so far I haven't been able to get it to work.

I get a SparkR dataframe (as I can't get Base R dataframes to work with RegisterTempTable()) and convert it to a temp table:

```
#Cell 1
jdbc_url <- "jdbc:sqlserver://myserver.database.windows.net:1433;database=mydb;user=user;password=*****"
df_R <- read.jdbc(jdbc_url, "(SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [schema].[table]) as result" )

SparkR:::registerTempTable(df_R,"df_temptable")
```

Then I try to read that back in as a pandas dataframe:

```
%python
#Cell 2:
import pandas as pd

pandas_df = df_temptable.select("*").toPandas()
```

which results in the error:

```
NameError: name 'df_temptable' is not defined
```

How do I successfully convert between R and python dataframes and back within Databricks (I would preferably like to go from a Base R dataframe to a pandas dataframe without using any Scala and in as few steps as possible)?

Answer (score -2):

From the error message `"NameError: name 'df_temptable' is not defined"`, it looks like `df_temptable` is not defined as the dataframe.

Here is an example to [convert spark DataFrames to and from Pandas DataFrames](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/spark-pandas.html).

```
%python

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Enable Arrow-based columnar data transfers
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true")

# Generate a pandas DataFrame
pdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100, 3))

# Create a Spark DataFrame from a pandas DataFrame using Arrow
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)

# Convert the Spark DataFrame back to a pandas DataFrame using Arrow
result_pdf = df.select("*").toPandas()
```